# Merge cells doesn't work after locking and unlocking other cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a sheet in which I'm trying to merge some cells based on CX cell value. CX cell is also dynamically locked/unlocked based on BX cell value. Although locking/unlocking works fine, I get 1004 error when I'm trying to merge cells with line:
`Range(Cells(Target.Row, i), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value - 1, i)).Merge`

While code is below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B14:B50")) Is Nothing And Sh.Name <> "Dane" Then
        Dim pass As String
        pass = "" 'set the password. Otherwise, protection/unprotection is done without a pass
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
        If Target.Value = "Unlocked" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect pass
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14:C50")) Is Nothing And Sh.Name <> "Dane" Then
        Dim i As Long
                
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
            If i <> 6 And i <> 7 And Cells(Target.Row, i).MergeCells Then
                Cells(Target.Row, i).UnMerge
            End If
        Next i
        If Target.Value <> 0 Then
            For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
                If i <> 6 And i <> 7 Then
                    Range(Cells(Target.Row, i), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value - 1, i)).Merge
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: When the error happens: What is  `Target.Value`?

Comment: The `Target.Value` is above 0.

Comment: I suspect that the cells you are trying to merge haven't been unmerged either because `Cells(Target.Row, i).UnMerge` comprises a range smaller than what is merged or because the instruction wasn't enabled. I suspect `If i <> 6 And i <> 7 And Cells(Target.Row, i).MergeCells` not to function as intended and would recommend `If i <> 6 And i <> 7 And Cells(Target.Row, i).MergeCells = True` if that turns out to be the case. Step through your code with F8 to observe what it really does.

Comment: If I remove `Cells(Target.Row, i).MergeCells = True` from function it's the same. I event changed `Range(Cells(Target.Row, i), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value - 1, i)).Merge` to `Range(Cells(Target.Row, i), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value - 1, i)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)` and have the same error. Is it possible, that this code have messed some cell proporties? Also, according to unmerge function, eg. I have merged cells B15:B18, and I unmerge only B15 cell.

Comment: I've found out, that if I manually unprotect the sheet, it works. But when sheet is protected, it doesn't, although I'm trying to merge cells in unlocked area.

Comment: Try unprotecting and protecting at the end, exactly as it is done in the first part of the code. I mean, place `ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass` after `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `ActiveSheet.Protect pass` just before `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`. Of course, do not forget to define the pasword (`pass`)...

Comment: That will work. However, why that error occurs even if I’m working with unlocked cells?

Comment: If you want me to read your comments addressed to me, **you must tag me (@FaneDuru)**. Otherwise, I can see your comment only if it happens to look on your question, supposing that I kept it open. So, in order to avoid an error, try using `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Put the lines in front or after `Application.DisplayAlerts = False/True`

Comment: @FaneDuru, `Application.EnableEvents` didn't change anything, but `ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass` solved the problem. However, why I need to unprotect the sheet if I'm trying to take an action at unlocked range?

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents` would be very important if unmerge would change a cell value in the range to be processed. In such a situation, the `SheetChange` event is triggered again... My suggestion meant a way to allow the event code to change cells without trigger the event continuously.

Comment: @FaneDuru, but it has to be added somewhere before and after `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0`, yup?

Comment: No. During the first condition the code cares only about B:B column. The code does not care about C:C column. It would be necessary if your code will modify something in the range "B14:B50". I suggested to manipulate `EnableEvents` only for the second condition, where it is not so clear if the Merge-Unmerge modifies something in the range "C14:C50".

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So with @FaneDuru comments, I've been able to figure out the issue. Sheet protection was causing the problem, so I had to unprotect and reprotect sheet before for loops in second condition. Also, @FaneDuru advised to set `EnableEvents = false` there, to prevent any infinite loop issue. Below is the fixed code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B14:B50")) Is Nothing And Sh.Name <> "Dane" Then
        Dim pass As String
        pass = "" 'set the password. Otherwise, protection/unprotection is done without a pass
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
        If Target.Value = "Unlocked" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect pass
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14:C50")) Is Nothing And Sh.Name <> "Dane" Then
        Dim i As Long
                
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
        For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
            If i <> 6 And i <> 7 And Cells(Target.Row, i).MergeCells Then
                Cells(Target.Row, i).UnMerge
            End If
        Next i
        If Target.Value <> 0 Then
            For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
                If i <> 6 And i <> 7 Then
                    Range(Cells(Target.Row, i), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value - 1, i)).Merge
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect pass
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If
    
End Sub
```

However, I'm still wondering why I need to unprotect the sheet to edit unlocked range.