# Macro treats single cell as range

Tags: excel, vba

In my code, I get runtime error 1004, "unable to set the Locked property of the Range class" every time if I change BX cell value from unlocked to any other. If I change any other value to unlocked code runs good. However, even if C column cells weren't previously merged the error occurs. Also, even if C cells where previously merged, they should be unmerged by `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "0"` this line, which calls second condition in my function. Why I'm getting this error?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim pass As String
    pass = "" 'set the password. Otherwise, protection/unprotection is done without a pass
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B14:B50")) Is Nothing And Sh.Name <> "Dane" Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
        If Target.Value = "Unlocked" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "0"
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect pass
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14:C50")) Is Nothing And Sh.Name <> "Dane" Then
        Dim i As Long
        Dim rng As Range
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
        For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
            If i <> 6 And i <> 7 And Cells(Target.Row, i).MergeCells Then
                Cells(Target.Row, i).UnMerge
            End If
        Next i
        If Target.Value <> 0 Then
            Dim cf As Boolean
            If Target.Value > 1 Then
                For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
                    If i <> 6 And i <> 7 Then
                        Range(Cells(Target.Row, i), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value - 1, i)).Merge
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
            For i = 14 To 50 Step 1
                If Not cf Then
                    Set rng = Range("A" & i).MergeArea.Resize(, 8)
                    With rng
                        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
                        .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin, Color:=RGB(142, 169, 219)

                    End With
                Else
                    Range("A" & i).MergeArea.Resize(, 8).Interior.Color = xlNone
                End If
                
                i = (i + Range("A" & i).MergeArea.Cells.CountLarge) - 1
                cf = Not cf
            Next i
            
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect pass
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `activesheet` is not necessarily the sheet being changed. Your code should use `sh` instead.

Comment: @Rory, thanks for your attention. However it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: A `Cell` is a `Range`, in fact. I cannot understand on which line the above error appears.

Comment: @FaneDuru, it occurs here: `Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True `

Comment: Apparent duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751127/merge-cells-doesnt-work-after-locking-and-unlocking-other-cell

Comment: Then, I would suggest you to previously check if the cell is not part of a merge area. Or, after modifying of my code you also added a sequence for C:C column, it needs `Application.EventsEnabled = False` followed by `Application.EventsEnabled = true` at the beginning and the code end.

Comment: Changing Col B triggers a change in col C, and the code for that reprotects the worksheet *before* you then try to lock the cell.

Comment: @Variatus problem fron previous question was with the sheet protection. When I modified code, as in answer, it was working fine. As you can see, the code in this question is modified further, where sheet is unprotected, but same error occurs not for same reason.

Comment: @Rory, thats right. Now I can see that issue. Thank you. Is there any more efficient way not to protect/unprotect for few times?

Comment: Assuming you mean for the col C code to run, at the start of that section, check if the sheet is protected and only reprotect if it was.

Comment: Did you try checking if the cell is already part of a merge area? Such a cell cannot be Locked.

Comment: @FaneDuru, it cannot be the part of a merge area, becouse macro sets its value to 0. It seems, like it's treated by Excel as merged are if sheet is protected. I don't know whether it's sort of bug or it's correct that way.

Comment: I am afraid, it can. If you try entering a value (in code) for a cell being part of a merge area, the cell will accept it, even if you cannot see any value, without raising an error. Try it! It will take a (visible) value only for the top left merge area cell.

Comment: @FaneDuru, but if I enter 0 there, it will unmerge these cells, so the error shoudn't occur at all. There is one more thing. Is there a way, to leave data validation while unmerging cells? In some columns in my sheet, there is data validation. While merging cells, it still exists, but if I unmerge these cells, only first one have data validation, rest not.

Comment: No. If you/your code enter/s 0, **those cells are not unmerged**. Please, test that, if you have doubts! It is a way of learning... Like I told you in a precedent comment, the value of an unmerged cell and its properties will be taken by the left top cell of the merged area. You can set a new validation after doing whatever you do. In code, of course...

Comment: @FaneDuru, Ive already checked that. It unmerges the cells. I know I can add new validation, but it’s probably easier to copy it.

Comment: Do you try telling me that having a merged area, let us say, "A4:C7" and you write a code line, let us say, `Range("B5").Value = 5`, the merged area will be automatically unmerged and you will see 5 at "B5"?

Comment: @FaneDuru I’m trying to tell you that if my code will add value 0 to C column cell, it will execute sheet chabge event once again and in second condition it will unmerge merged cells from a14 to hX.

Comment: It would do that **only if it would jump over the line `Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True`** but it cannot do that and raises an error. Telling that, I consider that I spent too much time on this issue. I wish you a nice day!

Comment: @FaneDuru, sheetchange event is executed once again after `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "0"` and before `Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True`. That was making sheet protected again before `Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True` and that was causing the problem. The code in question never try to  set `Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True` for merged cells. I wish you a nice day too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your code problem is the following:

Any change in "C14:C50" range (even done by first event part, a change in range "B14:B50"), will indeed trigger the second event part, which will merge/unmerge ranges as you want. I did not spend to much time to understand if all logic is OK.

The problem is that this second triggered event ends with `ActiveSheet.Protect pass`.

The first interrupted event **does not start from the beginning**. It continues from the line where has been stopped. Meaning that **the worksheet will not be unprotected in the moment you try locking a cell in C:C column**.

In order to solve the problem, please insert the next line:

```
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
```

just before:

```
Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
```

The inserted line, will unprotect the sheet in the situation described above, too.